# Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am working with stripe payment in flutter application. Flow is I am generating a token  of card and send to fire base later cloud function will get card detail and use stripe API to charge the payment I am facing a problem `npm install strip` successfully install the stripe but when I run the `firebase deploy` it shows the error.
here is I am writing cloud function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
//const firestore= admin.firestore();
//const setting ={timestampInSnapshots:true};
// firebase.setting(setting);
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)
exports.addStripeSource =functions.firestore.document('cards/{userid}/Tokens/{tokenid}}')
.onCreate(async (tokenSnap, context)=> {
   var customer;
   const data=tokenSnap.aftter.data();
   if(data == null){
       return null;
   }
   const token =data.tokenId;
   const snapshot =await firestore.collection('cards').doc(context.params.userId).get();
   const customerId=snapshot.data().custId;
   const customerEmail=snapshot.data().Email;
   if(customerId == 'new')
   {
       customer= await stripe.customers.create({
           email: customerEmail,
           source: token,
       });
       firestore.collection('cards').doc(context.params.userId).update  ({
           custId: customer.id,
       })
   }
   else{
       customer= await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);
   }
   const customerSource= customer.sources.data[0];
   return firestore.collection('cards').doc(context.params.userId).collection('sources').doc(customerSource.card.fingerprint).set(customerSource)

}
)
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems you installed `strip` instead you should install the following:

```
npm install stripe --save
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe

Comment: Add ur package.json

Comment: I edit the question kindly look once package.json file

Comment: the `package.json` should contain `stripe` in the dependencies, it means its not getting installed.. Are you sure their is no error when executing the command? Also check the `node_modules` of ur project to see if `stripe` was installed

Comment: I found this issue but I did manually add stripe dependency it also does not works.

Comment: I'm getting this error also.  Stripe is in 'dependencies' but not devDependencies.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. found out I needed to open terminal or command prompt and cd to the 'functions' folder for firebase and then run `npm install stripe` there. Once that was done, it worked.

Comment: Thanks. I forget to enter the folder.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you installed the package from the functions directory instead of the project directory. I accidentally installed packages while in the project directory, It works locally fine, but creates error when you deploy it. so,

```
cd functions
npm install [your package]
```

Then it will work fine

Comment: phew! was about to go crazy  "i have installed the dependency"

Answer (score 0):

steps:
this also worked for me i had done the install in the right folder as in firebase functions folder (backend), and was having problems when i tried to deploy it using:
firebase deploy --only functions Command, when the issue arose  i ran the firebase functions log command firebase function log: --only "Myfunction name here".
in the logs i found the error that: Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'stripe' so i installed stripe using:
npm install @stripe/stripe.js....this did not fix the problem! i had to install stripe like this first: npm install stripe and after this i ran the previous command: npm install @stripe/stripe.js
after this i ran the firebase deploy command: firebase deploy --only functions and voila! everything works - deployment complete! - hope this helps someone!