# Cannot find module 'stripe' during firebase deploy JavaScript functions in Flutter app

Tags: javascript, npm, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have added two firebase functions to my flutter app to implement Stripe.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.testKey)

const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
    prices = [];
    catalog = [
        { 'id': '0', 'price': 3.99, },
        { 'id': '1', 'price': 7.99, },
        { 'id': '2', 'price': 9.99, },
    ];

    items.array.forEach(item => {
        price = catalog.find(x => x.id == item.id).price;
        prices.push(price);
    });

    return parseInt(prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b) * 100);
}

const generateResponse = function (intent) {
    switch (intent.status) {
        case 'requires_action':
            return {
                clientSecret: intent.clientSecret,
                requiresAction: true,
                status: intent.status,
            }
        case 'requires_payment_method':
            return {
                'error': 'Your card was denied, please provide a new payment method',
            };
        case 'succeded':
            console.log('Payment succeded')
            return {
                clientSecret: intent.clientSecret,
                status: intent.status,
            };
    }
    return {
        error: 'Failed'
    };
}

exports.StripePayEndpointMethodId = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const { paymentMethodId, items, curency: currency, useStripeSdk, } = req.body;

    const orderAmount = calculateOrderAmount(items);

    try {
        if (paymentMethodId) {
            const params = {
                amount: orderAmount,
                confirm: true,
                confirmation_method: 'manual',
                currency: currency,
                payment_method: paymentMethodId,
                use_stripe_sdk: useStripeSdk,
            }

            const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(params);
            console.log('Intent: ${intent}');
            return res.send(generateResponse(intent));
        }
        res.sendStatus(400)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.send({ error: error.message });
    }
});

exports.StripePayEndpointIntentId = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const { paymentIntentId } = req.body;
    try {
        if (paymentIntentId) {
            const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(paymentIntentId);
            return res.send(generateResponse(intent));
        }
        return res.sendStatus(400)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.send({ error: error.message })
    }
});
```

However when I run the command `firebase deploy --only functions` it shows me an error. Here is the full log:

```
=== Deploying to 'jimv01'...

i  deploying functions
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8950

i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/fscozano/Desktop/GymPT_0.2/server/functions (75.05 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function StripePayEndpointMethodId(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function StripePayEndpointIntentId(us-central1)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'
Require stack:
- /workspace/index.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)
Could not load the function, shutting down.. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'
Require stack:
- /workspace/index.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)
Could not load the function, shutting down.. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        StripePayEndpointIntentId(us-central1)
        StripePayEndpointMethodId(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/jimv01/us/gcf
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function StripePayEndpointMethodId in region us-central1
- Error Failed to update function StripePayEndpointIntentId in region us-central1
```

Here is also the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

From the log, I assume that the problem is that it can't find the stripe module and, as you can see, the stripe dependency doesn't show even though I added it through the command `npm install stripe --save`. For this reason, I tried adding it manually:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
    "stripe": "^6.28.0"
  },
```

However, it shows another error:

```
=== Deploying to 'jimv01'...

i  deploying functions
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8640

i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/fscozano/Desktop/GymPT_0.2/server/functions (75.06 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function StripePayEndpointMethodId(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function StripePayEndpointIntentId(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Missing: stripe@14.21.0 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit]
npm ERR! [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2024-03-17T19_44_48_688Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Missing: stripe@14.21.0 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit]
npm ERR! [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2024-03-17T19_45_17_967Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        StripePayEndpointIntentId(us-central1)
        StripePayEndpointMethodId(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/jimv01/us/gcf
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function StripePayEndpointMethodId in region us-central1
- Error Failed to update function StripePayEndpointIntentId in region us-central1
```

Then, I discarded the option of manually adding the stripe module. Moreover, when I faced the first issue, the functions were loaded on firebase but with an error, so they are there but I can't use them.

Comment: Can you try downgrading the Firebase CLI Version and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159128/18265638) stripe package for stripe-node,  also check these suggestions in this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72856670/bug-in-firebase-cli-v11-2-0-error-cleaning-up-build-images) &  [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68611817/cant-deploy-cloud-functions-because-of-unhandled-error-cleaning-up-build-image)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I've tried doing so, but it doesn't work either. The stripe package is installed through npm but it can't find it somehow

Comment: After `npm install stripe` try running  this command  `npm install @stripe/stripe.js`  as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845533/18265638), also check this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-stripe-module-not-found-cant-resolve-at-stripestripe-js) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63064413/18265638)